# Regex find pattern and assign to variable python

Tags: python

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the package but i'm not finding a way to get a pattern.. My code is as follows:

```
    hexString = 'ddasdasdasdaee02ddsdsdda02ddbbsda02aaas02ss'
    hexList = []
    reg = re.compile(r'[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0][2]')
    test = re.split(reg, hexString)
    for s in test:
        if s:
            hexList = hexList + [reg.pattern, s]
```

The reg.pattern is giving me the actual pattern I input rather than the matching case... The .match function also just gives me an object to play with rather than the actual match itself.

I'm sure this is such a trivial solution but i've come up stuck.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: For every match I get, I want to assign it to a variable... and view what the match was.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output would be to have a list where it loops through the list and adds the pattern as the first element, then the string as second element, second pattern as third element, then string etc...

Comment: But once I know how to extract the actual values from the regex pattern then the rest I can do easily.

Comment: yes but what is the "pattern" you're after. Provide the exact output you expect from the input given,

Answer (score 0):

```
hexString = 'ddasdasdasdaee02ddsdsdda02ddbbsda02aaas02ss'    
match = re.findall(r'[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0][2]', hexString)
print match
```

**edit**

```
hexString = 'ddasdasdasdaee02ddsdsdda02ddbbsda02aaas02ss'
hexList=[]
reg = re.compile(r'[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0][2]')
match = re.findall(reg, hexString)
for s in match:
    if s:
        hexList = hexList + [reg.pattern, s]
print hexList
```